# raster2pgsql creates black and white tiles

Tags: postgis-2.0, raster2pgsql

im trying to build a tile from a geotiff however for some reason the output is black and white can anyone point out why and hopefully how to correct

here is a sample of the tiff

[image]

the import command was

```
raster2pgsql -s 27700 -a "{filename}" -F -t 100x100 "{table}"
```

here is a sample row from the db

"rid"   "rast"  "bounds"    "filename"
"842946"    "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"    "0103000020110F00000100000005000000E80292F065980FC1637D6391C0505A41F38D242824950FC1A5BE7CAFC0505A41140EC86820950FC10A41A390A6505A418CC8702E62980FC1DA418A72A6505A41E80292F065980FC1637D6391C0505A41"    "SO7.tif"

this is the query i'm using to pull the data out

```
  SELECT
  ST_AsPNG(
    ST_Resize(
      ST_Clip(
       (
         SELECT
           ST_Transform(
             ST_Union(rast),3857
           ) As new_rast
         FROM $schema.$table
         WHERE ST_Intersects(bounds, ST_TileEnvelope($z , $x , $y ) )
       )
       ,ST_Expand( 
         ST_TileEnvelope( $z , $x , $y ),1.05)
       )
       ,256
       ,256
       , 'Bilinear'
     )
   ) as raster
```

i did try this

```
ST_AddBand(ST_Union(rast,1), ARRAY[ST_Union(rast,2),ST_Union(rast,3)])
```

instead of

```
ST_Union(rast)
```

however the query failed because rast didn't have a 2 index

here is a sample of the output

[image]

Comment: I guess that your source image is single band image with a color table and conversion drops the palette.

Comment: that was my guess from the fact that the add band failed, though i can't tell at what point the colour is dropped or how to correct

Comment: I do not believe that PostGIS raster supports color tables. A paletted image is a grayscale image with a lookup table - pixel value x means color y. Maybe you should expand the paletted image into RGB before saving it into PostGIS is colors matter.

Comment: so the only solution is to convert the file before import?